# To generate laundau's prime numbers using python

Tags: python, primes

I want to generate list of primes of the format x<sup>2</sup>+1 but I am not getting any output.
My code:

```
def LPrime(n):

    for i in range(1,n):
        x = i**2+1;
        for j in range(2,x):
            if x % j != 0:
                print(x,i)
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.
The expected output should be something like

```
2,1
5,2
```

and so on
Also I am not able to execute it properly, I am using Ubuntu 22.04
There is no output when I try to

[image: terminal]

Comment: well, there are several things wrong, but one is that you are not calling LPrime(n).

Comment: Please add expected output for a given input.

Comment: You need to use `LPrime(10)` to call a function

Answer (score 1):

If `if x % j == 0:` you have a divisor. and `j` will not be `1` or `x`. So you should mark `p` as `False` (there is no prime). `else`, it is a prime; print it.

```py
def LPrime(n):

    for i in range(0, n):
        x = i**2+1
        p = True
        for j in range(2, x):
            if x % j == 0:
                p = False

        if p:
            print(f"Prime = {x},\t i = {i}")
```

Don't forget to call it

```
>>> LPrime(4)
Prime = 1,       i = 0
Prime = 2,       i = 1
Prime = 5,       i = 2
```

---

If you want `n` primes, use a `while` loop:

```py
def LPrime(n):

    count = 0
    i = 0

    while count < n:
        x = i**2+1
        p = True
        for j in range(2, x):
            if x % j == 0:
                p = False

        if p:
            print(f"Prime = {x},\t i = {i}")
            count += 1
        i += 1
```

```
>>> LPrime(4)
Prime = 1,       i = 0
Prime = 2,       i = 1
Prime = 5,       i = 2
Prime = 17,      i = 4
```

Comment: I am not able to execute it, I am using ubuntu 22.04, there is no output generated by this as well, I also tried online compilers but no success.

Comment: @YashashwiSinghania, updated - try again please

Comment: @YashashwiSinghania you're not including the `>>>` are you? if you are - remove them please

Comment: No I'm not, I am editing the original question to include this error

Comment: @YashashwiSinghania here's an online demo as well https://onecompiler.com/python/3y47z2rae

Comment: Thank you, the problem was me not calling it in the file, thank you so much!

Comment: @YashashwiSinghania no worries 